# Appropiate sample space for extraction of balls with certain conditions

Tags: probability, combinatorics, proof-verification

From a box that contains $5$ enumerated balls, one is picked at random, let that ball be the $k-th$ ball. The balls which number is greater than $k$ are taken out from the box and a second extraction takes place among the balls $1$ to $k$, let the ball of the second extraction be the $j-th$ ball. The balls with number greater than $j$ are removed from the box and a third ball is extracted between the balls $1$ to $j$.

a) Describe a sample space appropiate for this experiment and determine the number of elements that it contains.

b) Is it reasonable considering this space as equiprobable? What probability would be assigned to the element (1,1,1,)?

**Attempt at a solution**

I thought of a sample space by considering but I couldn't think of a compact way of describing it so I am going to present my $\Omega$ by describing directly all of the elements in it:$$\Omega=\{(5,5,5),(5,5,4),(5,5,3),(5,5,2),(5,5,1),(5,4,4),(5,4,3),(5,4,2),(5,4,1),(5,3,3),(5,3,2),(5,3,1),(5,2,2),(5,2,1),(5,1,1),(4,4,4,),(4,4,3),(4,4,2),(4,4,1),(4,3,3),(4,3,2),(4,3,1),(4,2,2),(4,2,1),(4,1,1),(3,3,3),(3,3,2),(3,3,1),(3,2,2),(3,2,1),(3,1,1),(2,2,2),(2,2,1),(2,1,1),(1,1,1)\}$$

So, $|\Omega|=35$ and in this case I think I could consider the space equiprobable, so $P(\{(1,1,1)\})=\dfrac{1}{35}$.

I would appreciate if someone could tell me if my solution is correct and if there is a simpler way of describing this space I've chosen for the experiment instead of enlisting all of its elements. I also encourage anyone who can think of another sample space that is not equiprobable.

Comment: Not sure I am following.  If the first ball I draw is $\#1$ then I remove numbers $2,3,4,5$, no?  In which case I am forced to draw $\#1$ again each of the second and third draws.  Thus the probability of the sequence $\{1,1,1\}$ is just the probability that the first draw is $\#1$, so $\frac 15$.  Or have I misunderstood?

Comment: Your set can be described compactly as $\{ (i,j,k) : 5 \geq i \geq j \geq k \geq 1 \}.$